# Python - Return a unique list of objects

Tags: python

I am trying to get a unique list of objects, I have some code that pulls data from an API and then puts that data into an object. I then put those objects in a list. however some of the objects are duplicates and I would like to know how to remove them?

sample list data:

```
[
Policy: 'SQL', 
SecondaryPolicy: 'ORACLE', 
Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer',
LevelNo: 1, 
StartDate: None, 
EndDate: None, 
StartTime: None, 
EndTime: None, 
Name: 'Fred', 
Mobile: '123', 

Policy: 'Comms', 
SecondaryPolicy: '', 
Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer',
LevelNo: 1, 
StartDate: None, 
EndDate: None, 
StartTime: None, 
EndTime: None, 
Name: 'Bob', 
Mobile: '456', 

Policy: 'Infra', 
SecondaryPolicy: '', 
Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer',
LevelNo: 1, 
StartDate: None, 
EndDate: None, 
StartTime: None, 
EndTime: None, 
Name: 'Bill', 
Mobile: '789', 

Policy: 'Comms', 
SecondaryPolicy: '', 
Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer',
LevelNo: 1, 
StartDate: None, 
EndDate: None, 
StartTime: None, 
EndTime: None, 
Name: 'Bob', 
Mobile: '456', 
]
```

code (ive removed some of the object data and put in sample data, for this test im just trying to get freds result returned once)

```
objPolicyData = getUserData()

OnCallData = [] 
for UserItem in objPolicyData['users']:   
    UserData = User()     
    #get the user object from DB
    UserData.Name   = 'Fred'
    for OnCall in UserItem['on_call']:    
        UserPolicy = OnCall['escalation_policy'] 
        UserData.Policy          = 'SQL'
        UserData.SecondaryPolicy = 'ORACLE'
        OnCallData.append(UserData)
```

attempts:
i tried this

```
clean_on_call_data = {User.Name for User in OnCallData}
```

but this only prints

```
set(['Fred'])
```

where are the other fields in the objects, and how would i iterate it?

EDIT: this is my class, is the cmp correct? how do i remove the duplicate?

```
class User(object):
    __attrs = ['Policy','SecondaryPolicy','Name']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr, None))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            ['%s: %r' % (attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self.__attrs])  

    def __cmp__(self):     
        if self.Name != other.Name:
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you post maybe some sample output of what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

**For Python 2.x**

I think you'll want to implement `__cmp__` for your class that stores the API data.

**For Python 3.x**

I think you'll want to implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` for your class that stores the API data.

Regardless of which version of Python, you can use the comparator / eq method to check for duplicates in your list. This can be done by utilizing `set(list)`, if you defined `__eq__`. As a set is a list of unique objects.

Comment: I think you got that mixed up. Python 3 doesn't know `__cmp__` anymore, instead you should implement at least `__eq__` and `__lt__`. Python 2 is what had `__cmp__`.

Comment: @L3viathan sorry about that, was pulling from memory! Edited to reflect that.

Comment: ive edited the question to include the _cmp_ function. have i implemnted it correctly. also the list stores the API data in classes, does that matter?

Comment: @GregHilston you would have to make sure that your objects are hashable though, right?

Comment: If you define your own `__eq__` you lose the built in `__hash__`. So you don't technically have to implement your own `__hash__`, but if you don't, you won't have one. Basically, if you write your own `__eq__`, write your own `__hash__` @FabianBosler

Answer (score 0):

How about using dictionaries and then a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Something like:

```
d1 = {
'Policy': 'SQL', 
'SecondaryPolicy': 'ORACLE', 
'Level': 'Primary On Call Engineer',
'LevelNo': 1, 
'StartDate': None, 
'EndDate': None, 
'StartTime': None, 
'EndTime': None, 
'Name': 'Fred', 
'Mobile': '123', 
}
d2 = {
'Policy': 'Comms', 
'SecondaryPolicy': '', 
'Level': 'Primary On Call Engineer',
'LevelNo': 1, 
'StartDate': None, 
'EndDate': None, 
'StartTime': None, 
'EndTime': None, 
'Name': 'Bob', 
'Mobile': '456', 
}
d3 = {
'Policy': 'Infra', 
'SecondaryPolicy': '', 
'Level': 'Primary On Call Engineer',
'LevelNo': 1, 
'StartDate': None, 
'EndDate': None, 
'StartTime': None, 
'EndTime': None, 
'Name': 'Bill', 
'Mobile': '789', 
}
d4 = {
'Policy': 'Comms', 
'SecondaryPolicy': '', 
'Level': 'Primary On Call Engineer',
'LevelNo': 1, 
'StartDate': None, 
'EndDate': None, 
'StartTime': None, 
'EndTime': None, 
'Name': 'Bob', 
'Mobile': '456', 
}


data = pd.DataFrame([d1,d2,d3,d4])

data[ data.Name=='Fred' ]
```

Which outs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the `User` class and implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` method, then just add those to a `set`, like this:

```
class UserUnique(User):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.Name)
    def __eq__(self, o):
        return self.Name == o.Name
```

Then you can do like this:

```
OnCallData = set()
for UserItem in objPolicyData['users']:   
    UserData = UserUnique()     
    UserData.Name = 'Fred'
    for OnCall in UserItem['on_call']:    
        UserPolicy = OnCall['escalation_policy'] 
        UserData.Policy = 'SQL'
        UserData.SecondaryPolicy = 'ORACLE'
        OnCallData.add(UserData)
```